# How Sort_index works in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to undestand how sort_index works in pandas. I ma quite confused with the results I got when i tested with two dataframes.

I have df1 sorted with index 'pid'

```
df1:
pid,day,score1,score2
100,Fri,200,108
......
221,Wed,546,789
221,Sat,123,456
```

The second data frame sorted with index 'pid'

```
    df2:
pid,day,score1,score2
100,Fri,230,18
......
221,Sat,563,324
221,Wed,111,789
```

I couldn't understand why PID# 221 is sorted differently in both cases. Ideally both should follow same sorting as i am sorting by index.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you **sure** that both dataframes are actually sorted? I remind you that `sort_index` is *not* in-place by default. It is better to provide the code that generates these dataframes

Comment: Yes. i used sort_index with inplace=True

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample data from the two dfs before sort? Most probably the order of occurrence the first PID# 221 is first in both of them.

Comment: Cause you have duplicated index

Comment: The order of occurrence in both cases are as per the sorting done in df1.  First comes 221,Wed,546,789  and then 221,Sat,123,456

Comment: I expect pandas won't change the order of occurrence while sorting.

Comment: @JitheshErancheri, please supply a reproducible example. What are your 2 input dataframes (a few rows are sufficient)? What do you get *for each separately* when you sort by index?